# Object view state with Unidirectional Data Flow with Swift and Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Swift with Realm to build an unidirectional data flow App.
I am wondering why I can not use an object as current application state.
`var people` is always updated when I add new person but `var oldestPerson` is never updated.
This is my Store.swift file

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var age: Int = 0
}
// MARK: Application/View state
extension Realm {
    var people: Results<Person> {
        return objects(Person).sorted("age")
    }
    var oldestPerson: Person? {
        return objects(Person).sorted("age").first
    }
}
// MARK: Actions
extension Realm {
    func addPerson(name: String, age: Int) {
        do {
            try write {
                let person = Person()
                person.name = name
                person.age = age
                add(person)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Add Person action failed: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
let store = try! Realm()
```

The state of `oldest` in my view layer never change but `people` change as it should.

```
import RealmSwift

class PersonsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var notificationToken: NotificationToken?
    var people = store.people
    var oldest = store.oldestPerson

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateView()
        notificationToken = store.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (_) in
            self?.updateView()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PersonTableViewCell") as! PersonTableViewCell
        cell.person = people[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func updateView() {
        print(oldest)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail, what do you mean but not updated? Is it not updated in UI for example?

Comment: @bcamur check my update

Comment: It works! Can you explain me why please?

Comment: I think I deleted my comment mistakenly. Did changing it to `var oldest: Person? { return store.oldestPerson }` work?

Comment: I'm not very sure of the reason but I guess your `var oldest` was set to the oldest Person at the moment your ViewController got initialised and it didn't get updated for some reason. It might be that `var oldest` was not getting set to `store.oldestPerson` when the notification arrived. You can try adding this line to your notification block `self.oldest = store.oldestPerson` to see if it was Realm related or Swift related.

Comment: Maybe it is because `oldestPerson` is not a query <Results> so it can not be up to date with changes made in the Realm.

Comment: Yes that makes sense actually.

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration of

```
var oldest = store.oldestPerson
```

to:

```
var oldest: Person? { return store.oldestPerson }
```

Comment: I think Unidirectional Data Flow should update the value of `oldest`. If I print `people` inside `updateView` it is always up to date, I do not need to get the value of `store.people` again like you told me for `oldest`. So I think your solution works but It does not explain why my `var oldest` is never updated.